# Has anyone had issues with multiple contact types showing as a result in Search Builder despite contact specification?

Tags: contacts

I've been using Search Builder to specifically find Journalists with two types of Media Interests, however my results have Talent and Media Outlets that do not have those Media Interests (two contact types I have not chosen).

I'm trying to get only Journalists, not Media OUtlets or Talent members.

Has anyone had a similar issue with multiple contact types showing up?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your custom field does not already enforce getting your desired contact type since other contact types have this field populated as well.

You can add a search field for contact type or contact subtype to limit your results to your desired type of contact.

Answer (score 0):

Rebekah - from the list you posted MOST of them show both the categories selected. The only ones (7th one down) that I can see that don't have them have a lot of others and may simply be pushing the ones you want to see out of sight.

Perhaps I don't understand your question but from what I see the result looks mostly right.

AH - If you are wanting to find records that ONLY have those two categories then I suspect Search Builder may not be able to do that in one step.

You may need to create a group of those above, and then create Groups for each of the categories you don't want to find, and use the Include/Exclude Custom Search.

Or do this via an sql query